# IDA Pro 6.4 android_server processattach failed

Tags: ida, debugging, android

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to solve the above mentioned problem I encounter. I was reverse engineering an apk, and met a part where static analysis with IDA Pro is not enough, so I thought that I could use the android_server provided by IDA Pro to debug the .so library during runtime. However, I kept getting an error from IDA Pro when trying to attach to any process within my emulator: 'The debugger could not attach to the selected process. This can perhaps indicate the process was just terminated, or that you don't have the necessary privileges.' I used adb to push the android_server to my emulator, and then used adb shell and executed the script as root, but I'm still having this error. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you have pushed the android_server to your emulator and executed it. So I guess you may forget forward your data from your development machine to your emulator.

As you executed the *android_server*, you can see `Listening on 0.0.0.0:23946...` in your emulator, which means *android_server* could kown what it should do by getting information from the **emulator's** port 23946.
Now, you need transfer the information from IDA to your emulator.

To do this, you need:

1. In IDA, click `Debugger` -> `Select Debugger`, choose a debugger accroding to your condition. For me, I choose *Remote Linux Debugger*.
2. Click  `Debugger` -> `Process Options`, and set ***hostname*** to **127.0.0.1**, then set  ***port*** to **23946** or some other port you want, which your IDA could use to send information.
3. In your development machine, as Windows, open cmd or powershell, enter `adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946`, so that your IDA can send data to your *android_server*. For more details for adb forward, please see https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports
4. If fortunately, now, in IDA, click `Debugger` -> `Attach to process`, you may see the processes list, which means success.

Answer (score 0):

I saw such issue in following situations:

1. When you run `android_server` as non-root user (without prior call to `su`).
2. When you run it with wrong working directory (as '/data/local/tmp/android_server`instead of`cd /data/local/tmp/ && ./android_server`).

So, please make you sure that you do everything exactly in correct way:

```
su
cd /data/local/tmp
./android_server
```

Otherwise it may not work.